# Developer Token approval?

Tags: google-ads-api

Normally how long will it take for Google to approve GAdwords developer token? I'd sent an email to Google Adwords APIs team in the month of Jan. but haven't hear back from them yet.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely follow up, a link in the chain may have been missed.  However, it can take several months - it did for me, despite the marketing team hammering Google repeatedly for results.  The company I work for spends many millions on AdWords every year, which does not necessarily make us a "big fish"... but if you're a lone developer it may take even longer.